# PointlnPolygon function not processing multiple objects from JSON Array

Tags: json, math, for-loop, google-maps-api-3, geometry

```
var polyLat = new Array();
polyLat[0]=10.194027;
polyLat[1]=10.200000;
polyLat[2]=10.200000;
polyLat[3]=10.226975;
polyLat[4]=10.243501;
polyLat[5]=10.254458;
polyLat[6]=10.304448;
polyLat[7]=10.269654;
polyLat[8]=10.161533;
polyLat[9]=10.059987;
polyLat[10]=10.002248;
polyLat[11]=9.920747;
polyLat[12]=9.885241;
polyLat[13]=9.854925;
polyLat[14]=9.853784;
polyLat[15]=9.835443;
polyLat[16]=9.899107;
polyLat[17]=9.948692;
polyLat[18]=9.993088;
polyLat[19]=10.029430;
polyLat[20]=10.046396;
polyLat[21]=10.063923;
polyLat[22]=10.081425;
polyLat[23]=10.072854;
polyLat[24]=9.992266; 
polyLat[25]=9.972824;
polyLat[26]=10.010875;
polyLat[27]=10.141595;
polyLat[28]=10.194027;//First point repeated to close polygon
var polySides = (polyLat.length)-1;//number of points in polygon
//vertical Longitude coordinates of polygon 
var polyLng =  new Array();
polyLng[0] =76.201205;
polyLng[1] =76.266667;
polyLng[2] =76.316667;
polyLng[3] =76.375022;
polyLng[4] =76.394118;
polyLng[5] =76.401347;
polyLng[6] =76.626291;
polyLng[7] =76.687660;
polyLng[8] =76.767483;
polyLng[9] =76.775730;
polyLng[10] =76.778940;
polyLng[11] =76.681244;
polyLng[12] =76.631163;
polyLng[13] =76.584336;
polyLng[14] =76.493901;
polyLng[15] =76.411473;
polyLng[16] =76.368070;
polyLng[17] =76.379645;
polyLng[18] =76.397007; 
polyLng[19] =76.385622;
polyLng[20] =76.365176;
polyLng[21] =76.362383;
polyLng[22] =76.317492;
polyLng[23] =76.281544;
polyLng[24] =76.267905;
polyLng[25] =76.244195;
polyLng[26] =76.215773;
polyLng[27] =76.178283; 
polyLng[28] =76.201205;//First point repeated to close polygon
//Coordinates for bounding box
var maxLat = Math.max.apply(null,polyLat);  
var minLat = Math.min.apply(null,polyLat);
var maxLng = Math.max.apply(null,polyLng);
var minLng = Math.min.apply(null,polyLng);


setInterval(function(){ob();},10000);

function ob()

{

$.post('outboundupd.jsp',
        {
    mx_lat:maxLat,
    mn_lat:minLat,
    mx_lng:maxLng,
    mn_lng:minLng,
    ply_sds:polySides
        },
        function(response,status,xhr)
        {

            plotdata(response);

});

}
    function plotdata(response)
    {
        var k;
        var x;
        var y;
        var mob;
        var jsonArray=JSON.parse(response.trim());
        var oblen= jsonArray.length; 
        var obj;
        for(k=0;k<oblen;k++)
        {
            obj=jsonArray[k];
            pcode= obj.Pcode;
            nplate= obj.N_plate;
            driver= obj.Driver;
            mob= obj.MobileNu;
            x= obj.Latitude;
            y= obj.Longitude;
            time= obj.Time;
            console.log(obj);
        }



        var j = polySides-1 ;
          oddNodes = 0;
          for (i=0; i<polySides; i++) {
            if (polyLng[i]<y && polyLng[j]>=y  ||  polyLng[j]<y && polyLng[i]>=y) {
                if (polyLat[i]+(y-polyLng[i])/(polyLng[j]-polyLng[i])*(polyLat[j]-polyLat[i])<x)  {
                    oddNodes=!oddNodes; 
                }
            }
           j=i; }




            if(oddNodes!=true)
            {

                $.post('obsouth.jsp',
                        {

                    pcd:pcode,
                    npt:nplate,
                    drv:driver,
                    mobl:mob,
                    lat:x,
                    lon:y,
                    tm:time

                        },
                        function(response,status,xhr)
                        {
                            response.trim();


                });

            }

          return oddNodes;

    }
```

in the above code, am getting multiple values from the JSON array in the **function plotdata(response)** and able to retrieve it using for loop but on passing it to the pointpolygon math equation defined on following line, am able to get only single set of data.

how to get all the values obtained in loop process the pointpolygon function?

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't using [containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#containsLocation) of the geometry library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You require the `pointInPolygon()`in the `for()` loop. As it is it only checks the last value of JSON array.

```
for(k=0;k<oblen;k++)
    {
        obj=jsonArray[k];
        pcode= obj.Pcode;
        nplate= obj.N_plate;
        driver= obj.Driver;
        mob= obj.MobileNu;
        x= obj.Latitude;
        y= obj.Longitude;
        time= obj.Time;
        console.log(obj);
        //pointInPolygon  HERE
    }
```

Comment: I had tried that way also but then it gives the first value while it was checking for the last value when the pointlnpolygon was outside the for loop. can you help me with the code? am really fed-up with this.

Comment: i got it. i misplaced the return statement inside the forloop. and the problem is solved now. thank you once again as it is your code :)